# Improve the usecase of a template-based library

Tags: c++, templates

I'm creating a lib in c++, using templates.

The problem I'm trying to resolve, the use case of itself is annoying.

First creates a container "Q_fun" with templates and the rest of classes use it, so all the classes have the same template parameters.

main.cpp

```
       lib::Discrete<unsigned> status(3),actions(21);
       lib::Q_fun<double,1,1> q(status, actions);
       lib::Agent<double,1,1> a(q);
       lib::Trainer_TD<double,1,1> tr(a);
```

Lib:

```
template<typename T, unsigned st, unsigned ac>
class Agent
{
  public:
    Q_fun<T,st,ac> *q;
...
}

... other file ...

template<typename T, unsigned st, unsigned ac>
class Trainer_TD
{
  public:
    Agent<T,st,ac> *a;
...
}
```

Do you know a better way to improve this(what can I change of the lib)?

Thanks 4 your time.
P.A.C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a type-trait:

```
template <typename T,unsigned st, unsigned ac>
struct my_types {
    using Agent_t = Agent<T,st,ac>;
    using Q_fun_t = Q_fun<T,st,ac>;
    using Trainer_TD_t = Trainer_TD<T,st,ac>;
};
```

Now the template parameters need not be repeated:

```
using types = my_types<double,1,1>;
types::Agent_t agent;
types::Q_fun_t q_fun;
types::Trainer_TD_t trainer_qd;
```